# Reading excel time value using OpenXML API

Tags: excel, time, openxml, type-conversion

I have an excel sheet which has a time column. Its time column is currently in the data type 'Time' (6:00:00PM), however, I've tried with 'Custom' data type (6:00PM) as well.

I read this cell value using openXML library as follows:

```
row.XCells[9].GetValue()
```

The value I read is .75. This is the value I see when I change the data type to number. I want to convert this to a timespan in my C# backend. How do I do that?

```
 var ts = TimeSpan.Parse(row.XCells[9].GetValue());
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel dates and times can be converted to C# `DateTime` using [`DateTime.FromOADate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Once you have the `DateTime` you can use the `TimeOfDay` property to get a `TimeSpan` (the `DateTime` will have a date of 30-Dec-1899 which is the OLE automation base date)

```
TimeSpan t = DateTime.FromOADate(row.XCells[9].GetValue()).TimeOfDay;
Console.WriteLine(t.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss")); // prints 18:00:00
```